# Batch delete by userDocID from React Firebase application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a social media app with React and Firebase and I need to batch delete from the "postLikes" collection by userDocID. For example, I need to delete all documents in the "postLikes" collection where userDocID == s5iVbDGC2dHOZZeGVyFg. How can I achieve this? Here is a screenshot of the collection:

[image]

This is the function I'm trying to add it to (the current functionality is working):

```
const removeFriend = async (friendUserID) => {

        const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userDocID);

        const friends = collection(db, 'friends');
        const q = query(friends, where("currentUID", "==", user?.uid), where("friendUserID", "==", friendUserID));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        const friendDocID = await querySnapshot?.docs[0]?.id;
        const friendDocRef = doc(db, `friends/${friendDocID}`);

        try {
            await updateDoc(userDocRef, {
                friends: arrayRemove(friendUserID) //removes the user from the friends
            })
            console.log("Friend removed");
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
        try {
            await deleteDoc(friendDocRef)
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }
```

Here are my imports:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import "./Draft.css";
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
import { auth, db, logout } from "./utils/firebase";
import { collection, doc, addDoc, getDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, Timestamp, query, orderBy, onSnapshot, getDocs, where, arrayUnion, arrayRemove, increment, writeBatch } from "firebase/firestore";
import { storage } from "./utils/firebase";
import {
    ref,
    uploadBytesResumable,
    getDownloadURL
} from "firebase/storage";
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import { convertToHTML } from 'draft-convert';
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { AiOutlineHeart } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { AiFillHeart } from 'react-icons/ai';
```

Answer (score 1):

We start by collecting all the documents to delete based on the`userDocId`, then we create a batch operation and proceed to iterate through each document in the collection, which then gets deleted.

```
const removeUserLikes = async (userDocId) => {
  try {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const userLikes = await db.collection('postLikes').where('userDocId', '==', userDocId).get();

    const batch = db.batch();
    userLikes.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    await batch.commit();
    console.log('Deleted documents' );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting likes:', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after adding that code even though I'm already using Firebase throughout my application: Line 323:24:  'firebase' is not defined.

Comment: Can you update your question with more code? How are you currently using it throughout your app now?

Comment: I added a little more code to my question. Does this help?